# resources for unit testing broad cast receiver

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit, broadcastreceiver

As I am new to unit testing can any one suggest me resources with sample examples for unit testing broad cast receiver. I want to get more information about broadcast receiver unit testing.I am using junit to test android applications. thanks for help in advance.

Comment: Can't you write a good ol' test function that you then setup as a handler of the broadcast? Start there, then you'll know how to do the unit tests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [MockContext](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/mock/MockContext.html) and override a few methods to see if you register the broadcast receiver and unregister it. But for the rest, normal testing should be enough.